# Drupal multisites on 'main' domain

Tags: drupal, multisite

I read on Drupal Multisites al each site is a seperate subdomain or directory like www.sub1.drupalinstance.com, www.sub2.drupalinstance.com or www.drupalinstance.com/sub1 and www.drupalinstance.com/sub2.

Is it also possible to have www.drupalsintance.com and www.samedrupalinstance.com?

Comment: If you mean single folder (site) with several domain , you can see Domain module https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

Answer (score 0):

You can manage several domain with Module Domain Access, see https://www.drupal.org/project/domain.

So your site is in single site configuration and have several domain.

Several methode to use Drupal :

Single site : only default folder is used

Multi site embed : Single site + Domain access Module

Multi site : you must have a folder for each site